# Shimano error code: LO EAT

Tags: shimano

On my Specialized Como electric bicycle, the Shimano display is showing LO EAT. What does this error code mean? I tried turning the bike off and back on again but the error display doesn't go away.

Comment: Lo Bat with a dodgy lcd perhaps? Add a photo!

Comment: Sounds to me like it's hungry!

Comment: Perhaps the display was too small to display "FEED ME SEYMOUR!"

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, your ebike has a main rechargeable battery and a separate coin cell battery in the controller, aka the TCD or Turbo Connect Display.

The warning says "LO BAT" for Low Battery, and you'll need to replace the CR2032 3V coin cell that keeps the bike's memory alive when the main battery is removed or flat.

I don't have one, but searching suggests you rotate the computer/head unit by 90 degrees, then it lifts off the mount.  Underneath is a common cr2032 access hole.  Rotate it with your fingers, or perhaps plier tips, then see the old battery inside and swap a new one in.

[image: From https://electricbikereview.com/forums/threads/turbo-connect-display-battery-replacement-tcd-lo-bat.38668/]

For more info, read the friendly manual at  https://media.specialized.com/support/collateral/0000108340.pdf

Note your odometer will be reset by changing the battery, so maybe you want to note it down first, if possible.   You may also need to re-pair the head unit with the other components, which is also described in the manual linked above.